# Erro de sintaxe no GLPK

Tags: sintaxe

```
set linhas;
set colunas; param c{j in colunas};
param A{i in linhas,j in colunas};
param b{i in linhas};

var x{j in colunas}>=0;

minimize FO: sum{j in colunas} c[j]*x[j];

s.t. R{i in linhas}:sum{j in colunas} A[i,j] = b[i];

end;
```

> Arquivo1.txt:3: syntax error in parameter data block
>   Context:                         set linhas ; set colunas ; param c {
>   MathProg model processing error

me ajudem a achar o erro de sintaxe?

Comment: Nunca usei glpk mas acho qur falta um enter antes do param c.

Comment: [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/) é uma linguagem inteiramente diferente de C: tag mudada.